# Automating the Webservice Testing

Tags: web-services, rest, selenium, soap

I am completely new to webservice testing.

I want to Automate the whole webservice testing part using a framework.

For eg : i have been given with a webservice say "10.0.0.191:8082/test/login"  and now i want to test its input and output result and validate it BUT with developing an automation script which does it for me. 
Say, like Selenium or cucumber which automates the complete website.  theres this Run button which starts the automation test and at the end gives me the report.

I want to develop something like this and i have no idea which framework is used and how to approach it.

Please help and Sincere Thanks in advance for your replies.

Comment: You have read the Selenium documentation, right?

Comment: @JoriO : yes i have read it.

Comment: To start with go with free version of `SoapUI` to test webservice in isolation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a webservice client and test the responses. The framework is little complicated as it will require you to know about the webservices.

Comment: sure, but could you guide me lil bit more about the framework.

Answer (score 0):

We use RestTest (author)

```
https://github.com/rawoke083/RestTest
```

Just dump all your service endpoint in a file with test conditions

```
#my.api.tests.txt
#http-method | endpoint | expected http return code | *optional text in response body
#example to test for 200 code and text "user-ok" in response with HTTP-GET

get|http://api.example.com/user?id=123|200|user-ok
```